# Получить html код php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть [страница](https://www.instagram.com/albina_nice777/). Нужно получить ее html код. Пытался получить `file_get_contents`, код получался, но не отображалась сама страница. Думая что дело в авторизации проверил через TOR и режим инкогнито, там отображалось корректно. Стал пробывать через `curl`

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/albina_nice777/'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$html = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
echo($html);
```

Не помогло. Не знаю что делать, прошу подсказать!

Answer (score 3):

Это инстаграм, он написан на реакте. А значит, html генерится на лету, сервером отдается js данные + статика js.
Для получения кода страницы послее рэндэра надо или использовать selenium/phantom, или же парсить js reactа базовый. Будь у вас нода, это было бы проще. На php плохо все